# Conditional probability with continuous uniform distribution

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

$X$ and $Y$ are independent uniformly distributed on $[a,b]$ random variables.

How to calculate
$$
P (Y<X \, | \, X>\frac{a+b}{2})?
$$
My calculations:
$$
P (Y<X \, | \, X>\frac{a+b}{2})=\frac{P(X>Y,X>\frac{a+b}{2})}{P(X>\frac{a+b}{2})}=
\frac{P(X>\max\{Y,\frac{a+b}{2}\})}{P(X>\frac{a+b}{2})}.
$$
It is obviously that the denominator
$$
P(X>\frac{a+b}{2})=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
But how to calculate the numerator?

Comment: so X is then uniformly distributed on [(a+b) / 2, b] - should you be integrating from 0 to (a + b) / 2, then from (a + b) / 2 to b

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a nice way to find this probability graphically. Unfortunately, my computer drawing skills are terrible. But the picture is as follows.

[image]

The rectangle represents all possible outcomes. The vertical line in the middle splits the outcomes into two parts: $X<(a+b)/2$ on the left and $X>(a+b)/2$ on the right. The diagonal line splits the outcomes again into two parts: $X>Y$ below the line and $X<Y$ above the line. Hence,
$$
P(Y<X\mid X>(a+b)/2)=\frac34.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Cm7F7Bb's graphical method is effective (and simple), but if you wish to do it via integration, a change of variables makes it easy too: $$\small\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>Y\mid X>\tfrac{(a+b)}2) ~=~& \mathsf P(S>T\mid S>\tfrac 12) &~:~& S=\tfrac{(X-a)}{(b-a)}, T=\tfrac{(Y-a)}{(b-a)}\\[0.5ex] ~=~& \int_{1/2}^1\int_0^s ~\mathsf d t ~\mathsf d s\Big/\tfrac 12 &~\because~&S,T\overset{\rm iid}{\sim}\mathcal U(0,1)\\[0.5ex]~=~& \dfrac 34\end{align}$$